# How do I change the Windows 8.1 background color?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

When I lock my computer and I go to the login screen there is a purple colored background. How do I change this?

I set this when Windows 8.1 was first installed.

Comment: Feeling embarrassed about your initial choice of color, eh? :) Too girlish color? Worried about nasty comments your co-workers might make if they see that? You can always put a paper bag over it. I'm just kidding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and type `accent` in the Search box on the right, and select *Change the Background and colors on Start*. Click on it and change the color.

[image: windows 8.1 win+w search setting]

Alternative method:

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> while viewing the Desktop and you will be taken to the Metro Menu. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> → Settings → Personalize → Choose your color.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that. I click it and it does nothing.

Comment: @ECMAScript What do you mean ? When you click on Change the Background nothing happens ?

Comment: I click on Change the Background and colors on Start and nothing appears

Comment: @ECMAScript check the my answer I updated it. But you should actually see colors from which you can choose when you click on Background and colors on Start.

Comment: I don't know about you, but clicking on the "Change the background and colors on Start" link is not resulting in any action, i.e. no settings window is shown. This is most likely a bug. I am using Windows 8.1 Pro with Update 1 and latest update, 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of the method posted by Devid. On my Windows 8.1 Pro computer I was unable to click on the "Change the background and colors on Start" link, as noted. This is high likely a bug. So I will show a slightly different way to access this setting, and also post some nice screenshot.

1. While viewing the Desktop, press the Windows key to show the Start
   screen.
2. Move your mouse pointer to the upper right corner of the screen and
   move it down.
3. Click on "Settings", and then "Personalize" at the top.
4. Pick a "background color".

[image: windows 8.1 personalize start screen background]

Answer (score 0):

Take your mouse p[ointer to the extreme right. 
Click **Settings**. 
Click **Change PC Settings**.
Click PC and Devices on the PC Settings app.
Choose the image you like, and exit.
If you want to use your image to set as lock screen background, hit **Browse** button below lock screen images.